# Android HTTPPOST request returns same page as I sent with

Tags: php, android, apache, post, http-post

I'm getting an insane headache because of this... I'm trying to log into this URL: http://www.johanstenberg.se/tests/app/signuptest.php which is built on this code:

```
<html>
<form method="post" action="signupresult.php">
username:<input type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" name="username"/>
password:<input type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" name="password"/>
client:<input type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" name="client"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
<html>
```

That code should send me to this website: http://www.johanstenberg.se/tests/app/signupresult.php which has this sourcecode:

```
<html>
<?php if(strcmp($_POST["username"], "matilda") == 0 && strcmp($_POST["password"],"password") == 0 && strcmp($_POST["client"], "TESTCLIENT1") == 0){
echo "accept";}
else{
echo "reject";}?>
</html>
```

This works if I manually put it into the first URL, but when trying to do it from an android asynctask it just returns the source code from the signuptest.php...

```
int TIMEOUT_MS = 10000;
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), TIMEOUT_MS);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), TIMEOUT_MS);
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(urlToSignupForm); 
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client", client));
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
String s = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

The String s is the source code for the first webpage (as mentioned before, signuptest.php). My code doesn't press the "button" or something, how do I make it to do that? Thanks in advance guys, I've been searching for hours now without any result!

Oh I should add that username, password and client all are "right", that is the required fields to generate "accept" in the signupresult.php.

Comment: Are you setting `urlToSignupForm` as signuptest.php or signupresult.php?

Comment: urlToSignupForm is signuptest.php :)

Comment: As a side note, there are libraries specifically for Asynchronous HTTP requests with Android. You don't *have* to use one, but I have found this one very helpful in the past: https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know what's wrong with my current code before changing the actual implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using signupresult.php as the URL you are connecting to since you're posting the data with the `HttpConnection`. For someone using a browser, they would go to signuptest.php to be presented with the form that they can fill out and have the browser submit to signupresult.php.

Comment: I want to make a baby with you. THanKS! (clarify, this was the problem)

Comment: Haha, glad to help. As some extra advice, you might want to consider using something like JSON encoded responses in singupresult.php so you can easily consume it with your app.